# SSL only working on half of site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, ssl

I have an SSL through Cloudflare and it only works on my main site, and not the wordpress part.

regular site:
http://championsdrivingschools.com

wordpress
http://championsdrivingschools.com/checkout/

If I do force SSL on the site it makes the wordpress look all it style and everything and it looks just like text

Comment: may be some included css, js or images url still having http on some pages. Please check information of the pages which url(s) causing the issue.

Comment: describe "not working"

Answer (score 0):

If you have added static URL in the pages without https then Url will not show green sign in the browser. please check static URL of any static assets and set below setting to make all pages with https.

**Step 1:** In your WordPress administrator dashboard, go to Settings -> General and change both URLs to have https:// rather than http://.

**Step 2:** These site asset files can easily be corrected by fixing the rewrite rules in your .htaccess file found at the root of your WordPress application.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

To get started, head to WooCommerce > Settings.

[image: check this checkbox]