# I Installed a new SSL and now only half of the site is secured?

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, https, lamp

> *Note: I checked similar posts but unfortunately I had no luck using their solutions*
>
> *Take for **example** this post, [SSL only working on half of site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618158/ssl-only-working-on-half-of-site) where the problem was that he only had the `https://` on half of the site, but the problem I'm facing is a bit different since I already have **https everywhere** yet my site is still half secure and half insecure in its own weird way.*

---

***Background:***
I just installed a new SSL certificate on my website running on a `Lamp Server - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version` inside a Google Cloud MicroServer.

---

***The Problem:*** After that, Both the `wp-admin` and the WordPress site ***itself*** were showing as insecure but without the red notice *(unlike self-signed)*, So I went back to my apache2 configuration and changed the `VirtualHost *:80 port to *:443` as well as the `ServerName myWebsite.com:443`,

I did this on both of the `.conf` files (SSL and the default) because I figured why use port 80?

`/var/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

`/var/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`

*(I remembered now that there's also the Listen command somewhere in the files that I forget and left on  Listen to port 80 that could be important)*

> **And only after I did that I got this weird new problem where only the wp-admin area is Secured while the homepage itself is `Info or Insecure` *(Google terms) - Unlike before I did that change where both the admin panel and the homepage was Insecure ***

*so I was finally happy to see that green secure icon but was sad to find out that it's only valid on the admin panel and not on the homepage which is very weird right?*

---

**Please take a look at the picture to better understand this weird problem:**

[image]

**I will really appreciate any help on the subject.**

**Thanks upfront.**

Comment: Have you tried to redirect http to https?

Comment: as mentioned in the top of the post, I already have https enabled everywhere on my site that's not a redirect problem but something else. take a look at the picture both the homepage and the admin panel is on https yet one is showing secure and the other is half secure, the blue button on the picture leads to this google post: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?visit_id=637034154368269546-3816287330&p=ui_security_indicator&rd=1 where my specific problem is the middle one "Info or Insecure" - Only on the homepage, which makes me think its a programming issue, maybe a simple code...

Comment: Do you have images on the site that are not secure?

Comment: That might be the problem man! let me check

Comment: I do see this error on the google console (inspector):
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.******/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.******/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/8204.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Comment: You could change the images path or even just force the server to redirect all http traffic through https.

Comment: how do I do that? please post it as an answer if you still can :) I will upvote you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an .htaccess file you can add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: If it worked select it as the answer. Again, not a problem, glad to help out.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

As turns out, I had that picture on my website which I uploaded before the SSL was added and now it's probably causing the problem, The easiest fix will be to download a Search And Replace plugin for Wordpress and replace `http://` with `https://`.

Thanks for @Tim Strawbridge for asking me the right questions

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.******/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://www.******/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/8204.jpg'. This content
>   should also be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Its no problem!